# List Result is null

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

```
StaticResource sr = [select body from StaticResource Where Name = 'kalpak'];

String contents = sr.body.toString();

LIST<String> alOne =new LIST<String>();

List<String> arrrrr = contents.split('\n');

for(String line:arrrrr) {

    alOne.add(line);
}

//here alOne List size is 4159 

//and each copf_id__c is associated with a Opportunity_ID__c

// but the below query return blank.

LIST<COPF_ID__c> alTwo = [SELECT Opportunity_ID__c,COPF_ID__c  FROM COPF_ID__c WHERE COPF_ID__c in :alOne];
```

Comment: Are the COPF_IDs inserted on the database? Or are you just getting values from the static resource?

Comment: Copf_id's are already present in the database,  i have those list of copf_id's in static resource file

Comment: No. Not in static resource. Do you have an actual record with that COPF_Id__c ?

Comment: Yeah it's around 50,000 records of Copf_id are present in database, I checked through workbech by executing the following query

Comment: SELECT Opportunity_ID__c,COPF_ID__c  FROM COPF_ID__c

Comment: Query Results

Returned records 1 - 200 of 520894 total records in 1.952 seconds:

Comment: Opportunity_ID__c COPF_ID__c
1 231244 091NEWD030002521354_171917
2 484759 11158141287_226164
3 103334 
4 106864 091HYDE030003510685_36287
5 106840 091PUNE030003510852_36292
6 094058 091GURG030003489243_36127
7 106877 091MUMB030003510725_36291
8 106930 52P251010
9 107517 1005_80P090508
10 107517 994_81P090508
11 107517 1228_82P090508
12 107517 994_83P090508
13 105364 8_134P080710

Answer (score 1):

From where I see, there could be two possible answers:

1) The COPF IDs on the static resource are not yet on the database. Check you static resource for that.

2) The splitting is wrong. If each Id is on one line, i'd suggest something like this:

```
//make sure all lines break the same way
List<String> arrrrr = contents.replaceAll('\r\n', '\n'); 
List<String> arrrrr = contents.replaceAll('\r', '\n');

//split list
List<String> arrrrr = contents.split('\n');

for(String line:arrrrr) {
    //remove whitespaces
    alOne.add(line.trim());
}
```